# Localization: Need English Version Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, csv

I'm having trouble reading a `NSLocalizedString` through my English `.csv` file.

In my app a user comes across a `UITableViewController` and selects a row. Whatever that row's title is is set to a global `NSString selectedRow` inside a `NSObject` (this NSObject is imported in every class). Once this occurs the next `UIViewController` reads `selectedRow`, runs through the `.csv` file until it comes across it, and then vomits all the information needed onto the `UIViewController`.

Example: `selectedRow = "About";` so in French this would be `selectedRow = "Environ";`

Now I don't have "Environ" in my `.csv` file, I have "About", so how would I force a `NSLocalizedString` to be English for a few moments without having to make a completely new French version of my `.csv` file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use NSLocalizedString then you would need to make .string files, if your CSV is actually static and want to translate words like "About" then you can follow the instructions [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) to add the .string files, make one for English, one for French, then if the user is using French as the Language Setting, they will see the content in French... If your .csv is not static and it constantly changes and has full sentences, then this probably wont work, and you would probably want to use a french version of the .csv file... You can localize it as described above too..

Hope this helps
Daniel